# Will raising upvotes on questions lessen the impact of downvotes to questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes

Because a downvote to a question is staying at -2, and upvotes to questions are increasing from 5 to 10, this will mean that the quality of a question needed to get net positive reputation goes from 1 upvotes/2.5 downvotes to 1 upvotes/5 downvotes, is this correct?

Perhaps I am making false assumptions here, or missing some other factor that may balance this effect out. I worry this could mean lower quality questions on a site where low quality questions is an issue.

Comment: Reputation gain and loss has no effect on questions and answers

Comment: @yivi I think you're right. I think it's answers that get -2, not questions

Comment: @KevinB Are you saying that reputation doesn't affect user behavior and how users ask questions and post answers?

Comment: No, but I feel it is important for there to be a distinction between what affects posts and what affects the people who make them.

Comment: In other words... will this change encourage people to write better posts? Will it encourage people to write more posts? Will it encourage people to ask another question when they otherwise would have moved on never to try again?

Comment: I suspect there will be a temporary bump in some if not all of those, however I also expect it to return to the same baseline.

Comment: It's now the same as with answers. Do you see that as encouraging people to write lower-quality answers? Why would questions be any different?

Comment: *I worry this could mean lower quality questions on a site where low quality questions is an issue.*  I found Shog's [answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42774/476162) interesting.

Comment: @CodyGray That's a good point. I think that's true. I know in my early days when I cared about reputation I poorly answered questions hoping for more upvotes than downvotes. This strategy often worked. In general, there's more of a problem with low quality answers than there is with low quality questions imho. Questions and answers are very different animals and I see no reason to treat them the same. I think having your question answered has been plenty reward to motivate people to ask questions

Comment: One significant difference is quantity. Poor, close-worthy questions flood in at a rate that curators can't even come close to keeping up, as seen by the size of the Close queue for the past few years. Poor answers, though numerous, are on a lesser order of magnitude *and* much less visible. The vast majority of people visit SO to find a solution to an issue, not to provide help to others, and those trying to provide help *usually* at least make an attempt to be helpful - which is why I'm more concerned with problematic questions.

Comment: @CodyGray "It's now the same as with answers." Just as a side comment on a more abstact level: There is no fundamental reason why questions and answers should be treated the same. Being different things, different rules may apply.

Comment: There was a study on one of the blogs or meta somewhere years ago discussing the psychological impact of a downvote.  Even on answers, where a downvote is just a fraction of an upvote, many people take downvotes personally (see all the "why did you downvote?" comments).  So while some people might not care about the quality of the questions they write, I don't think that's true of _all_ people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The impact of downvotes on questions is apart from the score change

- can trigger auto-deletion
- can trigger question bans
- decreases rep which can take away privileges

Now only the last part is affected by the recent change and mostly by inflating the gain of upvotes on questions which in turn means that the rep loss of downvotes is effectively reduced.

That means that people who are affected by this gamification would surely be compelled to ask more questions. The number of questions would surely increase if everything else stays the same.

It could be that users put more effort into the question quality in order to get more of this larger amount of rep per upvote.

It could also be that the question quality drops because why bother with quality, even with more downvotes or less upvotes the same rep gain can be realized now.

And maybe people even downvote less because the weight of a downvote is not very big, so why bother. That may decrease quality because downvotes are often a strong incentive to edit and improve. It could be less so now.

This could then in turn improve scores and lower quality at the same time.

As a summary: theoretically everything is possible, we will have to wait and statistically analyse the data in order to learn something. Just compare October 2019 with December 2019, but don't equate question quality with score right away. That might be misleading.

Comment: "And maybe people even downvote less" I can only talk for myself, but since yesterday I feel I take less attention of when the question has been posted and by whom before I downvote, exactly because my downvote has less power.